# how to save listview data while switching between fragments?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm developing an application that has 3 tabs (fragments) and one of them has a listview. I create BookmarksItem.java. It  implements Serializable and Parcelable. Here is my problem; when I click other fragments and back to listview fragment all data is lost. I  tried savedInstanceState putParcelableArrayList and get with getParcelableArrayList(key) on both onCreateView and onActivityCreated. It doesn't work unfortunately. How can I save data properly? Thanks allready

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use SQLite. After `onStop()` was called for a `Fragment` all your data is lost.

Here's a nice [tutorial for SQLite](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: Yes, i am using SQLite and i tried getAllColumns method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You 2 very easy ways

1) override `onResume` to instantiate the list again

2) store and load the list from/to a file with standard Java IO (or whatever you want)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how can i  handle?